# flex flex-row not working in array values mapped in VUE

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have created an array of items and mapped them in Vue but I can't make them to flex-row using Tailwind CSS maybe there is something I don't know about in tailwind css flex-row feature

```js
<div class="bg-white mt-5 rounded-tr-md rounded-tl-md">
     <!-- Filter menus -->
     <div
       v-for="filter in filterTypes"
       :key="filter.type"
       class="flex flex-row items-center px-5 py-4"
     >
       <div class="">{{ filter.type }}</div>
     </div>
     <!-- Transactions According to Pages-->
     <div></div>
   </div>
```

[image: The UI that I get back]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place `flex` to the parent element, and there's no need to `flex-row` since flex direction is row by default :

```html
<div class=" bg-white mt-5 rounded-tr-md rounded-tl-md">
     <!-- Filter menus -->
    <div class="flex items-center">
     <div
       v-for="filter in filterTypes"
       :key="filter.type"
       class=" px-5 py-4"
     >
       <div class="">{{ filter.type }}</div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <!-- Transactions According to Pages-->
     <div></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This not working. It flexes every thing in the application

Comment: So add an extra div that wrap the elements with v-for

Comment: Please check my edited answer